# Using this.GameObject

Tags: unity

I once read (I actually don't remember where, I'm looking for it) that using `this.GameObject` to call the script owner is a **very bad** practice.

I believe it has to do with some sort of *information hiding*, but I couldn't figure out why. What are the disadvantages with this? Is there a best-practice to achieve the result?

Comment: This question appears to be opinion based since any developer can have his own idea about what's a bad practice and what isn't. Not to mention what you're asking is also unclear. What alternative to this.gameObject do you know of?

Comment: @AlexM. I disagree. There really are some stuff that can be bad practise in terms of memory management and execution speed. For example using LINQ in real-time rendering code, and so on.

Comment: I once saw someone write this.transform.gameobject.collider.gameobject (or rather the equivalent to that; the exact chaining was unintentionally obfuscated through several intermediate variables). Now *that* was stupid code; the stupid part was not using this.gameobject in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bad practice.

From a point of view of a component, `this.gameObject` will always lead to a valid gameObject:

> A component is always attached to a game object. - [reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html)

That is, component cannot live without one. With `GetComponent<Type>()` there could be no component at all, so you should always check it or you could get crash caused by `NullPointerReference`.

The only bad practises about `gameObject`/`transform`/`components` getters are connected with using them heavily, multiple times on every update. Then you could consider some caching mechanism, for better performance results. See this [question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/185164/what-more-should-i-be-caching-within-my-scripts.html?sort=oldest).

EDIT: It seems like caching `gameObject` shouldn't make any improvements, but there is a speed gain by caching `components` (and yes, `transform` is a `component`). However, this stuff was also slower in previous Unity releases.

There is some useful time measured data comparison: [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/458762/are-gameobject-and-transform-both-using-getcompone.html).

Answer (score 2):

Bad practice, no. However, as with any reference, you have to be careful with it. Even though using it in general isn't bad practice, people can still find a way to use it in a bad practice way. Typically, `this.gameObject` is going to be a valid reference for as long as the script accessing it exists. Since the script is attached to the GameObject, it is also removed when the GameObject is.

Things to look out for:

- Expecting the same composition of every gameobject. For example, using `this.gameObject.GetComponent` to access a component, without testing if the component exists on the gameobject this script is currently attached to. The component based design of Unity means the script you're writing can be attached to any game object.
- Ensuring that the `gameObject` isn't missing, this can happen when destroying the game object, and still trying to access it, producing a MissingReferenceException exception. Typically this happens in other scripts keeping references to the `gameObject` of a different script.

Comment: For the first bullet point, can't `[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]` be relied on?

Comment: @Lasse For the most part. However, if the attribute is added *after* the component has been added to an object, it won't enforce the requirement. That is, the `RequireComponent` attribute is only enforced when adding a script to a game object.